# Send message between two blockchain nodes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum

I am confused about this issue.

How can I send message from user A to user B on blockchain network?

I have an illustration like this:

[image]

Assume, I have blockchain network with 5 nodes. Each node represents one "Organization".

How can User A in Organization 1 send message to exact User B in organization B?

I guess, we can send message between two blockchain nodes, for example node 1 and node 3 or other node in blockchain network. But, at User A, how he can determine "where is User B"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, the answer itself is **Blockchain**. At the end, a Blockchain network what provides you is the following one: the validated and verified information that is registered in the network is sent to all the participants of the network.

In the case of `Hyperledger-Fabric`, you would have to generate a channel for organizations 1 and 3 of your ilustration. In this way, only those two organizations will see the data registered by User A.

Comment: Hi, Mr Urko, can you show me how Blockchain " Blockchain network what provides you is the following one: the validated and verified information that is registered in the network is sent to all the participants of the network.", for example. Thank you.